# how to get select2 dropwdown to stay at constant width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I am using select2 for a dropdown in a form and I like using a table layout (although maybe this is part of the problem?) to keep the widths of all of the form-group elements the same.

The problem is that when I type text into the select2 dropdown, the width changes (and in weird ways). Is there a way I can force the initial width that the browser gives the select2 dropdown to remain fixed?

Here is my html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Title</label>
                    <input name="title" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>a label</label>
                    <input class="form-control"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>a label</label>

                    <select id="tag_list" class='form-control' multiple="multiple">
                        <option value='1'>abba</option>
                        <option value='2'>zabba</option>
                        <option value='3'>doo</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="category_type">Category Type:</label>

                    <select name="category_type" id="category_type_list" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>If there is a matching type for the category, please select it</option>
                            <option value="1">A</option>
                            <option value="2">B</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="row action">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="inline">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit">submit</button>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="inline">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary cancel">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and my css:

```
.form-group{

    display: block;
}

table {
  margin-left: 5%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

input {
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.inline{
    float:left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

span.select2-container{
    width: 100% !important;
    tex-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/eop468ns/3/) is a fiddle example. You can try it out by typing something long enough into the select2 dropdown and pressing enter seeing that the width changes. How can I stop that from happening?

Comment: so you have this fixed? I have some ideas but I don't see a real issue with your fiddle.

Comment: no, its not fixed. In the fiddle, in the third input which has a placeholder of "a short description..." type something long (a few words) and then press enter. You will see that the width changes when you press enter. I want to stop that from happening

Answer (score 0):

I Added a new css class that seems to work aimed at that specific select box.
The + is equivalent to the jquery next function.  This should get you pointed in the right direction.  Just to be safe, make sure this is set after you load the select2 css.

```
 #tag_list + .select2-container .select2-selection--multiple {
    max-width: 400px;
  }
```

So if you want the search box to be the same size for all select2s (single or multi ) then try...

```
   .select2-container  .select2-dropdown, 
   .select2-container .select2-selection--multiple {
    max-width: 300px;
  }
```

I turned the last select box into a select2 and tried this.
What I am doing is using the DOM explorer built into IE to find the element that is giving me issues and what classes are being applied. Then I simple overwrite or append them.

Comment: this makes the other inputs not be the same width. What I want is to keep the width from moving from its original width. I guess i'm being unclear?

Comment: I added a second part that would apply to all

Answer (score 0):

by setting `width=100%` as below

```
<select id="tag_list" style="width:100%; display:block;" class='form-control' multiple="multiple">
 <option value='1'>abba</option>
 <option value='2'>zabba</option>
 <option value='3'>doo</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

.select2 dropdown to stay at constant width in table tag use below style in your code

```
<style>
    .select2-container{
        width: 100% !important;
    }
</style>
```